# Minha tabela não mostra os dados apesar de o código estar igual

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

Não consigo entender o motivo de não apresentar registros na minha tabela quando mudo a referência para `dataTable2.js`, apesar de o código estar igual ao exemplo que mostra os dados. Se puderem me ajudar com este jQuery e `dataTable`, agradeço.

Meu código `dataTable2.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var data = [
        {
            "name":       "Tiger Nixon",
            "position":   "System Architect",
            "salary":     "$3,120",
            "start_date": "2011/04/25",
            "office":     "Edinburgh",
            "extn":       "5421"
        },
        {
            "name":       "Garrett Winters",
            "position":   "Director",
            "salary":     "$5,300",
            "start_date": "2011/07/25",
            "office":     "Edinburgh",
            "extn":       "8422"
        }
    ];
    // $("#example").DataTable();

    $("#example").DataTable({
        "language": {
            "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
            "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix": "",
            "sInfoThousands": ".",
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ resultados por página",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
            "sProcessing": "Processando...",
            "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
            "sSearch": "Pesquisar",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sNext": "Próximo",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                "sFirst": "Primeiro",
                "sLast": "Último"
            },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
            }
        },
         "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        fixedHeader: {
            header: true,
            footer: false
        },

        data: data,
        columns: [
            { data: 'name' },
            { data: 'position' },
            { data: 'salary' },
            { data: 'office' }
        ]
    });
});
```

Código que peguei como exemplo `dataTable.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //setando os dados da tabela na variável data

    var data = [
        {
            "name":       "Tiger Nixon",
            "position":   "System Architect",
            "salary":     "$3,120",
            "start_date": "2011/04/25",
            "office":     "Edinburgh",
            "extn":       "5421"
        },
        {
            "name":       "Garrett Winters",
            "position":   "Director",
            "salary":     "$5,300",
            "start_date": "2011/07/25",
            "office":     "Edinburgh",
            "extn":       "8422"
        }
    ];

    $("#example").DataTable({
        "language": {
            "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
            "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix": "",
            "sInfoThousands": ".",
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ resultados por página",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
            "sProcessing": "Processando...",
            "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
            "sSearch": "Pesquisar",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sNext": "Próximo",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                "sFirst": "Primeiro",
                "sLast": "Último"
            },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
            }
        },
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        fixedHeader: {
            header: true,
            footer: false
        },

        //OBRIGATÓRIO
        data: data,
        columns: [
            { data: 'name' },
            { data: 'position' },
            { data: 'salary' },
            { data: 'office' }
        ]
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- jQuery DataTable -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

  <!-- script DataTable -->
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Botstrap DataTable -->
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css"> -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css">

  <script src="dataTable2.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p></p>
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped" data-order='[[ 1, "asc" ]]' data-page-length='10'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th data-class-name="priority">Salary</th>
          <th>Office</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Estranho, não há nada errado no código, pois o mesmo roda perfeitamente ao reproduzir no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/doxg4oe7/). Veja qual a saída no console do browser, para ver se existe algum erro sendo impresso. Se houver, adiciona na pergunta a imagem do erro.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção Renato Diniz, verifiquei o código que eu tinha e identifiquei erro de sitaxe, agora funcionou bem.